# How to implement sending a message to a specific user?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I want to send a message to a specific client, but the server script implements sending a message to the connection id, going through all the keys on an array.

pieces of server code:

```
//sets ID when connecting and adding to array:

var wsServer = new webSocketServer({ httpServer: server });

wsServer.on('request', function(request) {

    console.log((new Date()) + ' ws from origin ' + request.origin + '.');

    var ws = request.accept(null, request.origin); 
    var id = clients.push(ws)-1; 

    console.log((new Date()) + ' ws accepted. ID:' + id); // show ID

//////////


var json = JSON.stringify(res);
for (var i=0; i < clients.length; i++) {
    clients[i].send(json);  // sent to all connected clients
}
```

I want to send messages to a specific user with arbitrary user_id
  example: clients[user_id_from_database].send(json);

As written in the array "my_user_id_from_database" when connecting?